# How to Insert multiple Records from HTML Table Rows

Tags: html, records

The following HTML Code displays input fields for Single Record and provides for saving this Single Record to the Database

```
   <html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="demo_add.asp">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>CustomerID:</td>
            <td><input name="custid"></td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td>Company Name:</td>
            <td><input name="compname"></td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td>Contact Name:</td>
            <td><input name="contname"></td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td>Address:</td>
            <td><input name="address"></td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td>City:</td>
            <td><input name="city"></td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td>Postal Code:</td>
            <td><input name="postcode"></td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td>Country:</td>
            <td><input name="country"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Add New">
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

How is possible to save multiple such records in One Operation?

Comment: What framework are you using? I see demo_add.asp but are you required to use ASP.NET?

Comment: I will be using PHP. The sample code I copied from Internet. I am new to HTML and CSS.  
I was primarily trying to understand how to use <div> and .css with JS to save multiple records from HTML table to any database

Comment: The form will pass all those input values as a POST request to the backend. What you do from their depends on what framework you are using. I don't know much about PHP web frameworks but I would recommend using such frameworks for most things.